# Flutter - Custom draw signature inside container not working

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am using this code below I found while searching stack overflow on ideas about saving a signature as a custom drawing. I made a small change mentioned in the comment and I can now draw, BUT... it draws on the entire screen and not inside the box which is what I want. I also want to save this image as base64 format but that is after I make the white area contain the signature inside.

```
    [![import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:sitereport/Constants/Constants.dart';

class Signature extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SignatureState createState() => _SignatureState();
}

class _SignatureState extends State<Signature> {
  List<Offset> _points = <Offset>\[\];

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(\[
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    \]);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(\[
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
    \]);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey\[700\],
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>\[
          Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            height: 200,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              boxShadow: \[
                BoxShadow(
                    color: constructionOrange,
                    offset: Offset(0.1, 1.0),
                    blurRadius: 5.0,
                    spreadRadius: 1.0)
              \],
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            child: Stack(
              children: \[
                GestureDetector(
                  onPanUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails details) {
                    RenderBox referenceBox = context.findRenderObject();
                    Offset localPosition =
                    referenceBox.globalToLocal(details.globalPosition);

                    setState(() {
                      _points = new List.from(_points)..add(details.localPosition); //Using local position above was drawing below the white area
                    });
                  },
                  onPanEnd: (DragEndDetails details) => _points.add(null),
                ),
                CustomPaint(painter: SignaturePainter(_points))
              \],
            ),
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: <Widget>\[
              GestureDetector( // SAVE BUTTON
                child: Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 20.0),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 25.0, vertical: 10.0),
                  child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        'SAVE',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 15.0, color: Colors.white),
                      )),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: darkYellow,
                    borderRadius:
                    BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
                    gradient: GRADIENT,
                  ),
                ),
                onTap: () {
                },
              ),
              GestureDetector( //CLEAR BUTTON
                child: Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 10.0),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 25.0, vertical: 10.0),
                  child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        'CLEAR',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 15.0, color: Colors.white),
                      )),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: darkYellow,
                    borderRadius:
                    BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
                    gradient: GRADIENT,
                  ),
                ),
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _points.clear();
                  });
                },
              )
            \],
          )
        \],
      ),
    );
  }
}





class SignaturePainter extends CustomPainter {
  SignaturePainter(this.points);

  final List<Offset> points;

  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = new Paint()
      ..color = Colors.black
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
      ..strokeWidth = 4.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < points.length - 1; i++) {
      if (points\[i\] != null && points\[i + 1\] != null)
        canvas.drawLine(points\[i\], points\[i + 1\], paint);
    }
  }

  bool shouldRepaint(SignaturePainter other) => other.points != points;
}][1]][1]
```

Comment: use `clipRect()` inside `paint(Canvas canvas, Size size)` method

Comment: Thanks. canvas.clipRect() is asking for an argument, what would that be?

Comment: a `Rect` you want to clip all of your drawing code - everything drawn outside that rect will not be visible

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on 'how' it is done as a one line code, please? I have a container which is 200 in height and width is double.infinity inside which I want to 'contain' this

Comment: `Offset.zero & size`

Comment: It stops drawing when I add canvas.clipRect(Offset.zero & size)

Comment: what is `size` in your case?

Comment: I am not sure, my complete code is in the listing above. I just added the parameters as given by you.